# Surface reconstruction error - PCL 1.6

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, point-cloud-library, win64

I followed exactly the tutorial I found [here](http://www.pointclouds.org/assets/icra2012/surface.pdf), with some modification for the input. Then my code is:

```
#include <common/common.h>
#include <io/pcd_io.h>
#include <features/normal_3d_omp.h>
#include <surface/mls.h>
#include <surface/poisson.h>
#include <pcl/io/vtk_io.h>
using namespace pcl;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 1)
    {
        PCL_ERROR ("Syntax: %s input.pcd output.ply\n", argv[0]);
         return -1;
    }

    PointCloud::Ptr cloud (new PointCloud ());
    io::loadPCDFile ("ism_test_cat.pcd", *cloud);
    MovingLeastSquares mls; mls.setInputCloud (cloud);
    mls.setSearchRadius (0.01);
    mls.setPolynomialFit (true);
    mls.setPolynomialOrder (2);
    mls.setUpsamplingMethod (MovingLeastSquares::SAMPLE_LOCAL_PLANE);
    mls.setUpsamplingRadius (0.005);
    mls.setUpsamplingStepSize (0.003);
    PointCloud::Ptr cloud_smoothed (new PointCloud ());
    mls.process (*cloud_smoothed);
    NormalEstimationOMP ne;
    ne.setNumberOfThreads (8);
    ne.setInputCloud (cloud_smoothed);
    ne.setRadiusSearch (0.01);
    Eigen::Vector4f centroid;
    compute3DCentroid (*cloud_smoothed, centroid);
    ne.setViewPoint (centroid[0], centroid[1], centroid[2]);
    PointCloud::Ptr cloud_normals (new PointCloud ());
    ne.compute (*cloud_normals);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < cloud_normals->size (); ++i)
    {

        cloud_normals->points[i].normal_x *= -1;
        cloud_normals->points[i].normal_y *= -1; cloud_normals->points[i].normal_z *= -1;
    }

    PointCloud::Ptr cloud_smoothed_normals (new PointCloud ());
    concatenateFields (*cloud_smoothed, *cloud_normals, *cloud_smoothed_normals);
    Poisson poisson;
    poisson.setDepth (9);
    poisson.setInputCloud (cloud_smoothed_normals);
    PolygonMesh mesh;
    poisson.reconstruct (mesh);
    io::saveVTKFile ("sreconstruc.vtk",mesh);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using PCL 1.6, VS2010, all x64.

VS2010 doesn't detect any errors in the code and so I compiled it. But when I execute that, it has a problem:

```
'Unhandled exception at 0x000007fee833546b (pcl_kdtree_debug.dll) in pcl_surface-reconstrucTutorial.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.'
```

The terminal shows this `[pcl::NormalEstimationOMP::compute] input_ is empty!`.

The code is executed up to 'mls.process (*cloud_smoothed);' line.

How could I solve it? I'm going crazy to solve it.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: The file I used as input is [this](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/data/blob/master/tutorials/ism_test_cat.pcd)

Comment: are you using the default values given in the tutorial? and also the same file? It can happen that if you use other file you need to tweak the values a bit and then you get result. (input will not be empty at normal estimation)

Comment: Are you sure you are indeed reading the point-cloud file? Please try to use the full path (not just 'name.pcd'), because when  loadPCDFile tries to find a file, but the file does not exist at that path, you don't get an exception, and the program continues execution.

Comment: @dim.tziwnas, I check the load of the file, insterting 'io::savePCDFileASCII("hello.pcd",*cloud);' just after the load function. It saves correcty the file. I also changed the setup parameters for MovingLeastSquares function like [here](http://justpaste.it/dd9p) but nothing. It doesn't process anything!!

Comment: hi all, as @Laszlo-Andras Zsurzsa said, I changed parameters, and now it goes on. But now, when it executes and saves file.vtk. When can I find a good explanation of parameters to obtain a good mesh? For example what is the best of them for file I used! Thank you very much again, mainly to Laszlo-Andras Zsurzsa

Comment: Post you're solution that others can see. Sadly there is no good explanation in any of the tutorials. You have to look into the code and if there is an article check that on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Laszlo-Andras Zsurzsa said, I changed parameters, and now it goes on. But now, when it executes and saves file.vtk. I use [this](http://justpaste.it/ddnn) setting to get something good

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough repulation so I use answer as comment for Akash question.

When using Poisson reconstruction, you just care with 2 parameters: deep of octree and number samples per node of octree. In PLC, author of Poisson algorithm set deep of octree is 8 and samples per node is 1.0. You can change deep to 10 to having smoother surface result (more time consume, of course). Author said that you should stop at 10 because more bigger number, more time needed. Samples per node of octree should in between 1.0 to 1.5 so I think it has nothing exited to change.

For question when we should use Poisson algorithm: the answer is when you need to reconstruct a watertight (close) object because Poisson algorithm use indicator function to reconstruct suface so its result is always watertight.

If you want to try other Poisson implementations in past, you can find them in this [link](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/Code/PoissonRecon/Version6.13/)