# PCLVisualizer.addPolygonMesh doesn't show anything

Tags: visual-studio-2010, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

using [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391828/surface-reconstruction-error-pcl-1-6) I want to visualize mesh.

I use [this](http://justpaste.it/ddwv) code snippet, just after poisson.reconstruct function.

Running it, the viewer shows nothing, and the terminal says that there is no mesh.
Why? Is there an error? Where? How to solve?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to call the `spinOnce()` method in the loop:

```
visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("Simple Cloud Viewer"); 
viewer.addPolygonMesh(mesh);
while(!viewer.wasStopped()) {
   viewer.spinOnce(); 
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html) [this method](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/classpcl_1_1visualization_1_1_p_c_l_visualizer.html#a896556f91ba6b45b12a9543a2b397193) updates the screen.